# Macro identifier undeclared even if it is declared

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have this error coming up when I try to compile my C project.

`error #20: identifier "someGetFunctionMacro" is undefined`

This comes up at the line where I am using `someGetFunctionMacroB()` in my code.

`variable = someGetFunctionMacroB();`

But here is what `someGetFunctionMacroB()` is abstracting.

```
#define someGetFunctionMacro()      someGetFunction(param1)

#define someGetFunctionMacroA()     (someGetFunctionMacro == returnval1 ||\
                                     someGetFunctionMacro == returnval2 ||\
                                     someGetFunctionMacro == returnval3)


#define someGetFunctionMacroB()     someGetFunctionMacroC() && (someGetFunctionMacroA() == 1)
```

I do not understand why the error is coming out when clearly identifier `someGetFunctionMacro` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function-like macros must be used like functions, with parentheses and all.

So if you have a macro like

```
#define someGetFunctionMacro()      someGetFunction(param1)
```

you *must* "call" it like a function with the parentheses.

In the `someGetFunctionMacroA` macro definition you don't use `someGetFunctionMacro` correctly.

Comment: Omg you are correct! I tried this and now the compilation error above is gone. Thank you!